# Best Practices for Development Backups

Tags: development-environment, backup-strategies

I am a intermediate-level developer (I think). I almost always work alone.

I have always just save my code to my hard drive and then published it to my server. I almost always over-write old code. If I make a big mistake I will get a backup restored from my web host. Obviously this can be a pain and cost time.

I know there must be a better way. I guess I could just save copies each time I change a file but that seems like it could get confusing too if I have 1000 different versions each time I make a minor tweak.

What is the best solution? It seems GIT type services may be more hassle than it is worth in my situation.

Comment: Check out [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com). They have [free private repository hosting](http://onveracity.com) for up to five users. I use Veracity all the time at work for little projects. There's a bit of a learning curve, but I really like it now. If you have specific questions, make sure you checkout their [Q&A](http://veracity-scm.com/qa) area of the site.

Comment: Set up Git with a remote server. It's not that much of hassle for what you want to use it for.

Comment: I think software config mngmt (SCM) can be helpful, even if you work by yourself.  For one thing, you're prepared if you ever start working with another developer.  Also, (1) it's easier to maintain multiple release versions (e.g. different feature sets, different platforms, etc.) of your product; (2) you can work on long term or experimental features without disrupting your near term development; and (3) it's much easier to roll back changes if you find you've gone down the rabbit hole and need to backup to a known-good point.

Answer (score 0):

You work on the wrong way...
Try a [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System), that kind of software administrate versions and changes by itself.

Read about how implement a [SVN solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29), that will help you a lot.

GIT, Codeplex and other repositories are based on that kind of tools.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in steps:

### Source control

Google has a full list of articles, if you use GIT, this is my favorite:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

and see this other
www.bignerdranch.com/blog/you-need-source-code-control-now/

but Source control isn't just a backup.

See 
[Is there a fundamental difference between backups and version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549600/is-there-a-fundamental-difference-between-backups-and-version-control)

### Backup your Source

You need a copy of your code in a backup server, site or external dispositive.

GIT or Subversion is for source control not for copy.

see "Backup Best Practices: Read This First!"

and set a tool for this work periodically.

### Software Configuration Management

You need set a system for the software change, step by step, start with the user needs and cover all methodology work

see redmine ...